# Npm start doesnt work after I create a react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm following a youtube react tutorial and what I did was npx create-react-app my-app  Once this was done I cd'ed into my-app and tried to npm start like the tutorial showed. 
I got an error saying 
*-npm ERR! missing script: start* 
I also saw that the person in the tutorial had a public and a source folder. I only have the node_modules folder and package-lock.json and package.json. Why am I missing the public and source folders and why cant I npm start?

Comment: you didn't mention run script on package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it running : `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`.

Thanks to the `-g` (aka 'global' attribute) you can run this terminal command no matter the directory you find yourself.

Then go in the directory you would like to find your project and run `npx create-react-app my-app` again!